# Using chained join method in Python

Tags: python-2.7

```
t=('1','2','3')
print '-'.join(t).join(t)
```

The output of above code is

> 11-2-321-2-33

How?

Comment: Small correction: what you're describing is really a chained join, not a nested join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so let's break down "print '-'.join(t).join(t)" into two separate method calls.  Because functionally, this is what happens in the program.

**First call:**  '-'.join('1','2','3') will return '1' + '-' + '2' + '-' + '3' or in short '1-2-3'.  I substituted 't' with its actual values in the program.  The result of this method call will then be used as input for the second method call.  Which brings us to..

**Second call:**  '1-2-3'.join('1','2','3') will return '1' + '1-2-3' + '2' + '1-2-3' + '3' or '11-2-321-2-33'

Hope this clarifies this for you

Answer (score 0):

What's actually happening is that Python is evaluating your expression by first solving the inner "join" - which outputs "1-2-3", then using that string to join your tuple. Let's call that first string "-AaA-" - what you see in the end is basically: 1-AaA-2-AaA-3. only instead of my string, you get the tuple joined by "-", surrounded by the tuple.

it's the same as:
'1-2-3'.join(t)